# Consulta SQL para filtrar una tabla utilizando dos tablas

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Actualmente tengo 4 tablas SQL de esta forma:

CustomersTable, RegistrationTable, OrdersTable y OffersTable

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo que escribir una sentencia SELECT que liste todos los clientes de la tabla CustomersTable (todos los campos), los cuales contienen filas en la tabla RegistrationTable o filas en la tabla OrdersTable con status "closed", en la tabla de resultados no debe mostrar clientes duplicados.

Como se puede ver, CustomersTable y RegistrationTable tienen el campo en común "customerId", pero entre CustomersTable y OrdersTable no hay campo en común. Sin embargo, hay otra tabla (OffersTable) que tiene los campos "customerId" e "ID", de modo que se pueda consultar información a las tablas clientes y órdenes respectivamente. Recuerde que un cliente que aparece en la tabla Offer no necesariamente aparecerá en la tabla Order o simplemente el campo status no podria ser "closed".

Por lo tanto, al ejecutar la consulta, se devolverá el resultado siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la tabla de resultados no debe mostrar clientes duplicados. Realmente aprecio la ayuda. Gracias por eltiempo !!

Nota - Estoy utilizando MySQL

Comment: ¿y que query tienes? ¿en que falla?

Comment: He utilizado la siguiente sentencia :                                                                       select c.*
from customers c
where exists (select 1 from registrations r where r.customerid = c.customerid) or
      exists (select 1
              from offers o join
                   orders oo
                   on o.id = oo.orderid
              where o.customerid = c.customerid and
                    oo.status = 'closed'
             );

Comment: Agrégalo a tu pregunta, será útil para cuando alguien quiera responderla :)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: y aclara por favor que datos devolvió esa consulta

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas y sugerencias ! Correre la sentencia SQL con la data real y subire el resultados.

Comment: Tambien revisare la seccion de guia para realizar las preguntas, aun no estoy muy familiarizado con el funcionamiento de este medio. Gracias por los tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a utilizar la sentencia IN, yo uso SQL server pero me imagino que MySQL tendrá la misma sentencia o alguna que sea similar.

```
SELECT * FROM customer 
WHERE 
    customerID IN (SELECT  customerID FROM registration) AND 
    customerID IN (SELECT customerID FROM OFFER, ORDER WHERE OFFER.id=order.id AND status='closed')
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias @user2506141 y Xerif, utilice la sentencia y devuelve los resultados aunque con unos detalles. Muchas gracias por el aporte !